# Attribute Routing for ApiControllers from external assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a large ASP.NET MVC 5 application, and now I want to implement Web API for it. But I want to put ApiControllers in a **separate project.**

I have problem with organizing routes for the Web API:

I want my main application Routes by

```
host/*
```

And the API maps on

```
host/api/*
```

And for the API, I want to use Attribute Routing, but can't setup WebApiConfig with proper way.

How to organize this, retaining the ability to use "Attribute Routing"?

Comment: What's the reason for implementing Web API on your project? Is it to serve existing and new UI features, in which case I would ask, is it really necessary to introduce another layer into an already large MVC app? or is it to provide a set of services for external/third party integration to your domain?

Comment: Yep, we plan to reimplement UI on ClientSide, and and give API access for third party services. Old parts of BigApp will wither away bit by bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

For ApiControllers it is not necessary to reimplement Factories.

In project Web (main), we need:

1. Add dependency to project with ApiControllers
2. Edit Global.asax this way

   replace:

   ```
   WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
   ```

   to

   ```
   GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
   ```
3. in WebApiConfig.Register

   ```
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
   ```

   to enable Attribute Routing.

Now the Web API engine can find all ApiControllers in the Scope.

Answer (score 0):

In your WebApiConfig class:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("myaction")]
    public IHttpActionResult MyAction()
    {
       //code
    }

    [Route("otheraction/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult OtherAction(int id)
    {
       //code
    }
}
```

Now, the routes for this controller and these actions will be mapped like this:

{host}/api/myaction 
{host}/api/otheraction/{id}

Hope it helps